# How could I structure this React Native Section List implementation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-sectionlist

So I want to use RN Section list in a sort of unorthodox way.

I want the section list to pass off rendering to a component as the renderings won't be very uniform.

I want to use section list so as you scroll you still get to see the headers.

I made a component that takes in children and renders them in a section list like so:

```
class SomeSectionList extends Component {

    render() {
        let sections = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (Child, index) => {
            return {title: Child.type.title, data: [''], renderItem: () => Child, index }
    });

        return (
            <SectionList

                renderSectionHeader={({section}) => {
                    return <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{section.title}</Text>
        }}
                sections={sections}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

And the usage would be something like:

```
                <SomeSectionList>
                    <Comp1 />
                    <Comp2 />
                </SomeSectionList>
```

However, my issue is. Say in this case Comp1 does not render anything from it's component, I want to be able to hide it's section from the section list.

How could the `SomeSectionList` component know that it didn't render anything or didn't have the data to render anything so it can hide it's section and it's header?

Any suggestions would be great. I feel like using SectionList for this is overkill (but it makes showing the headers nicer) so open to alternatives as well.

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish this using `onLayout` method that comes with `View`.

By which we can get the height of the component rendered. if it is 0 that means nothing is rendered inside it or else it contains some data.

See this [Working example on snack](https://snack.expo.io/@jdgalani6297/sectionlist-with-null-render-to-remove)

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SomeSectionList>
        <Comp1 />
        <Comp2 />
        <Comp1 />
        <Comp2 />
        <Comp1 />
      </SomeSectionList>
    );
  }
}

class Comp1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Comp11</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

class Comp2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

class SomeSectionList extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      children: this.props.children,
    };
  }
  onLayout = (event, index) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.layout.height <= 0) {
      let oldProps = this.state.children;
      oldProps.splice(index, 1);
      this.setState({ children: oldProps });
    }
  };
  render() {
    let sections = React.Children.map(this.state.children, (Child, index) => {
      return {
        title: Child.type.title,
        data: [''],
        renderItem: () => (
          <View onLayout={event => this.onLayout(event, index)}>
            {this.state.children[index]}
          </View>
        ),
        index,
      };
    });

    return (
      <SectionList
        renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => {
          return <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{section.title}</Text>;
        }}
        sections={sections}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Here, first of all, we have assigned `this.props.children` into state. Then in `onLayout` method, we are checking if the current indexed child has 0 height or not. if yes then remove it from the array of children.

You'll see clearly that some views are deleting. for this thing what we have done in one scenario is put one loader that covers the whole `SectionList` area with position absolute and you can hide it when all things are rendered correctly.

Comment: This is great, thanks @jaydeep. Do you think this is bad for section list performance? My worry is it's not taking advantage of  maybe some intelligent stuff it does for knowing the height of the cells like removeClippedSubviews and getItemLayout. But not sure, any thoughts?

Comment: Also, say a component renders 0 height, but then later renders a height, is there a way to hide it and then show it. Kinda weird because the component doesn't get mounted. Might be tricky

Comment: Glad you find it helpful and yeah if your sectionlist if too much heavy like 300+ data a little bit performance will be down. but only a fraction of second.

Comment: and for your second concern it will automatically hide and show because onLayout method will be called again if layout or height changes.

Comment: That's a very nice idea to do.

Comment: @JaydeepGalani the issue is since the component gets removed from the section list if it's height is 0, so it's not mounted, so say I call setState on that component which causes it to re-render I get a an error like "can't call setstate on an unmounted component". Any ideas?

Comment: when nothing is rendered in a component then why did you need to have `setState`? If you still want to do this, then make some changes in the component run time(i.e. change some passed props or anything else), that changes its height from 0 to higher. then, it will be rendered again, now you can do anything like a normal component.

Comment: I see, so even if the component isn't mounted via the sectionlist, if props come into it, say through redux, and it later renders something, the onLayout will still be triggered? (even if it's not mounted). Will give that a try, thanks!

Comment: @JaydeepGalani can't seem to get this to work. The use case is say at first the section renders nothing. But later, they get a friend request for example, so we want to show the `friend requests` section. But since that section is already removed from the sectionList I don't seem to have any way to add it back in. Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonovono I have updated code in snack see, click on 3rd `Comp11` and click `Mount again`.

Comment: ya that makes sense @JaydeepGalani, thanks! It's not ideal because the parent component doesn't know this info. Ideally the child can change it's height and the parent can pick that up independently, but don't think that will work. But this might be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate that I am thinking after the helpful advice of @JaydeepGalani!!

```
class SomeSectionList extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
            hiddenChildren: {}
    }
  }


  onLayout = (event, index) => {
    if (event.nativeEvent.layout.height <= 0) {
            const hiddenChildren = this.state.hiddenChildren
            hiddenChildren[index] = true
            this.setState({
                hiddenChildren
            })
    } else {

            const hiddenChildren = this.state.hiddenChildren
            delete hiddenChildren[index]
            this.setState({
                hiddenChildren
            })
    }
  }

    render() {
        let sections = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (Child, index) => {
            return {
                title: Child.type.title, 
                index,
        data: [''], 
        renderItem: () => (
          <View onLayout={event => this.onLayout(event, index)}>
            {this.state.children[index]}
          </View>
      )}
    });

        return (
            <SectionList

                renderSectionHeader={({section}) => {
                    const index = section.index
                    if (this.state.hiddenChildren[index]) return 

                    return <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}>{section.title}</Text>
        }}
                sections={sections}
                keyExtractor={(item, index) => item + index}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

Since in the first implementation once the section got removed it's really hard to bring it back as the onLayouts don't get triggered. In this we still technically 'render' the section, but hide the header and since the section is of height 0 it won't show up, but it's still rendered and say at a later point in time that section changes and suddenly renders something it will now show up in the section list.

Curious on any feedback around this?